# Issue with an Insert Query with a IsDuplicate flag check sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Server stored procedure that inserts a row into a table. It has a subquery that checks for duplicates.

In the production environment, some duplicate rows are not getting flagged correctly.

I suspect it has something to do with concurrent query processing where when the second record is inserted, the `spIsDuplicateStatus` is failing because the `SELECT` statement is not returning anything due to prior row not being inserted yet.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertTransactionDetail]
   @pTransactionID VARCHAR(100),
   @pCurrentDtTm DATETIME2(3),
   @pMessageID varchar(50),
   @spResult int OUTPUT,
   @spIsDuplicateStatus bit OUTPUT         
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

    BEGIN TRY
        IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[TransactionDetails] 
                   WHERE MSGID = @pMessageID) 
        BEGIN
            SET @spIsDuplicateStatus = 1;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @spIsDuplicateStatus = 0;
        END

        INSERT INTO dbo.TransactionDetails(TRANSACTIONID, CREATED_ON, ISDUPLICATE, MSGID)
        VALUES (@pTransactionID, @pCurrentDtTm, @spIsDuplicateStatus, @pMessageID);
    
        SET @spResult = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH             
        SET  @spResult = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END
```

Does anyone have any pointers as how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; why have you tagged both? What RDBMS are you *really* using? The above looks like T-SQL, which would mean SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Im using. MS SQL Server. I edited the tags

Comment: If you want to stop duplicates, why is there not a Primary/Unique index on the column that needs to be unique? The short answer is, yes, the above can (will) suffer from race conditions, and so 2, or more, of the *same* value could be inserted.

Comment: I dont want to stop dupicate records, but identify them using a flag in the table

Comment: You'll likely want to explicitly *lock* the table and use a transaction then, to stop other sessions connecting.

Comment: `SET  @spResult= ERROR_MESSAGE();` makes no sense; you can't assign an error mesasge to an `int`.

Comment: Use transaction and updlock hint.

Comment: Seems over-complex. Why isn't it a single `insert` statement with an `exists` check?

Comment: I'd say this design is bad altogether. A duplicates column becomes stale very quickly. When you insert new duplicates, the old rows don't get updated either.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be tested, as we have no sample data, etc, but i would likely do something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertTransactionDetail] @pTransactionID varchar(100),
                                                            @pCurrentDtTm datetime2(3),
                                                            @pMessageID varchar(50),
                                                            @spResult int OUTPUT,
                                                            @spIsDuplicateStatus bit OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @spIsDuplicateStatus = COUNT(ID)
    FROM [dbo].[TransactionDetails] WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE MSGID = @pMessageID;

    INSERT INTO dbo.TransactionDetails (TRANSACTIONID,
                                        CREATED_ON,
                                        ISDUPLICATE,
                                        MSGID)
    VALUES (@pTransactionID, @pCurrentDtTm, @spIsDuplicateStatus, @pMessageID);

    SET @spResult = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    COMMIT;

END;
GO
```

Firstly, I enable `XACT_ABORT`, so that the whole process rolls back in the event of an error, due to the declaration of an explicit transaction.

I then assign the `COUNT` of `ID` to your `bit` column; this will work as `0` will assign `0` and any other positive number will result in `1` being assigned. You'll also note I use an `UPDLOCK`, which will stop other sessions from being able to *read* that row until the transaction declared ends; meaning the avoidance of race conditions.

Then, finally, I `INSERT` the values, assign the `IDENTITY` to your `OUTPUT` parameter and `COMMIT`.

I completely removed the `TRY...CATCH`; it was pointless and would actually cause an further error as you try to assign the error **message** to an `int`. Just have the error thrown automatically, and you can handle that outside if needed. If you do need explicit logic in the `CATCH`, it should be more than you had (and make sense).

Comment: Hello Thom, thank you for your answer.

Basically, for my problem to be solved, we need to make sure that the duplicate records SP call's select statement should run **after** the original records SP call's insert statement is run. 

Im not quite sure how this solution handles this scenario, Is it the combination of UPDLOCK and TRANSACTION ? could you please elaborate ?

Comment: By adding UPDLOCK, + TRANSACTION COMMIT is the duplicate record SP going to wait till the original SP is run ?

Comment: It will do, yes, @rajeevbk , because the row(s) it wants to check exist are locked. This is needed, as otherwise you will just be back in the position you are and have race conditions.